# Reset iPhone without iTunes or iCloud?

Tags: iphone, ios, itunes, backup, restore

I need to reset an iPhone. My grandmother somehow locked her iPhone with a pin and no one knows the code. I have a backup of her phone in my iTunes but I need to reset the phone before I can restore that backup.

When I attempt to restore the phone it tells me it has a problem downloading the software. I've tried on multiple computers. There isn't an iCloud account for this phone so I cannot reset it using that method.

How do I reset the phone so I can restore it and get it working again?

It's an iPhone SE running the latest iOS.

Comment: If find my iPhone is turned on you have issues, if not you have no problem...

Comment: Is this a sim pin or a password?

Answer (score 1):

If, as you say, there is no iCloud account associated with that phone then restoring it using the DFU method should work. (This method applies when iPhone is on and plugged into a Mac with iTunes open)

- Hold down the Power and Home buttons on the iPhone until the screen goes black
- Continue holding Power and Home for two seconds after the screen goes black and then release the Power button, while still holding Home
- iTunes will display a message saying it has detected a device in DFU mode (or recovery mode) and will give you an option to restore it. Release the buttons.

If you're having issues with the actual download of the IPSW file itself then that'll be either your internet having issues with the download or Apple's software server having issues with delivering it.